# How to get port forwarding working with Jelastic to connect to REPL of running Clojure web app?

Tags: portforwarding, jelastic

I've deployed a simple Clojure web app to Jelastic in a Tomcat container. The Clojure app starts a REPL on port 7001. I have Jelastic SSH Gate set up and working. I SSH into the tomcat node with port forwarding by running this in the terminal on my local machine (where XXX are numbers):

```
ssh -L 7001:localhost:7001 XXXXX-XXXX@gate.paas.massivegrid.com -p 3022 -N -vv
```

Then on my local machine I run

```
lein repl :connect 7001
```

On the local machine I see:

```
Connecting to nREPL at 127.0.0.1:7001
ConnectException Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

On the tomcat node terminal window I see

```
debug1: Connection to port 7001 forwarding to localhost port 7001 requested.
debug2: fd 10 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug2: channel 2: zombie
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 7001 for localhost port 7001, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 57311 to 127.0.0.1 port 7001, nchannels 3
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this something to do with the way that Jelastic manages ports?

=====================

#### EDIT: Actually port forwarding works fine

The problem was with the app.

For reference, here's how to check that port forwarding is working on Jelastic. The Jelastic node doesn't have netcat installed so you can't just run `netcat -l 7001`. However, it does have perl installed, so you can write a perl script to create a listener socket and then run that script on the Jelastic server:
(EDIT 2019_04_06: Instead of using perl script below, just use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7001` - see comments)

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
 
# auto-flush on socket
$| = 1;
 
# creating a listening socket
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    LocalHost => '0.0.0.0',
    LocalPort => '7001',
    Proto => 'tcp',
    Listen => 5,
    Reuse => 1
);
die "cannot create socket $!\n" unless $socket;
print "server waiting for client connection on port 7777\n";
 
while(1)
{
    # waiting for a new client connection
    my $client_socket = $socket->accept();
 
    # get information about a newly connected client
    my $client_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
    my $client_port = $client_socket->peerport();
    print "connection from $client_address:$client_port\n";
 
    # read up to 1024 characters from the connected client
    my $data = "";
    $client_socket->recv($data, 1024);
    print "received data: $data\n";
 
    # write response data to the connected client
    $data = "ok";
    $client_socket->send($data);
 
    # notify client that response has been sent
    shutdown($client_socket, 1);
}
 
$socket->close();
```

(script from [here](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-write-simple-tcp-server-and-client-in-perl.html)).
Use nano to write the above into a script listener.pl on the Jelastic node then run `perl listener.pl` on that node.

On your local machine run

```
ssh -L 7001:localhost:7001 XXXXX-XXXX@gate.paas.massivegrid.com -p 3022
```

Then on local machine try `curl localhost:7001` and in the terminal for the Jelastic node you should see something like

```
received data: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7777
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
```

Comment: If the problem isn't with Clojure then you should drop the clojure tag.

Comment: Fair point. Removed tag.

Comment: @toby-one We checked port forwarding the way you used and it works for us. Can be related to local or application issues. You can try [Endpoints](https://docs.jelastic.com/endpoints) and if don't help, [write us](https://jelastic.com/contact/) directly

Comment: You're right @Jelastic it does work. I've added a note to my question explaining that it does work and also with notes about how to test that it's working. If you know an easier way to test the connection than what I've described that would be great - I had to use a perl script in place of netcat because the ```nc``` command wasn't reconised on the Jelastic node.

Comment: @toby-one You can use pre-installed SimpleHTTPServer. Run 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7001' inside necessary dir. Hope this helps.